# How could I parse this json-string?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a string:

```
[{"data1":"A"},{"data2":"B"},{"data3":"C"}]
```

I used jQuery to convert this string to json:

```
test_json = $.parseJSON('[{"data1":"A"},{"data2":"B"},{"data3":"C"}]');
```

I got 3 objects:
[image]

I don't know, how could i get the key and value in this string-json?
Or the format of string-json is wrong?

Comment: I did, and it's same XD

Comment: Calling `toString` on an object will (almost) always give you `[object Object]`. Your code is just fine. Try doing `console.log(test_json[0])`.

Comment: @MikeC I got this string in Console:       {data1: "A"}

Comment: well, that's the key and value...which is what you asked for.

Comment: You have an array, so the first object is `test_json[0]` The first key of the object can be found with `Object.keys(test_json[0])` this returns you the array `["data1"]`, so `Object.keys(test_json[0])[0]` gives you "data1". The value is then `test_json[0][Object.keys(test_json[0])[0]]`. You might just want to use a loop though instead of hardwiring the indexes.

Comment: Side note, you can use `JSON.parse()` for this. No need to use jQuery.

Comment: @ADyson I could see the key and value. But how could print the key and the value separately?

Comment: "I used jQuery to convert this string to json" — **from** JSON, not to, from!

Comment: @Shilly Perfect! Thank you! You understood what i meant and solved my problem.

Comment: @YingStyle You can get an objects keys using [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys). You can then use those keys to get the values.

Comment: @Quentin I have a string, and i convert it to json object.

Comment: @YingStyle see https://jsfiddle.net/bzjemtoc/

Comment: @YingStyle — No, you have a string of JSON which you convert to a JavaScript Array of Objects. See also http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried cycle thorough the parsed array?

```js
var test_json = $.parseJSON('[{"data1":"A"},{"data2":"B"},{"data3":"C"}]');

for(var a=0;a<test_json.length;a++) {
    var obj = test_json[a];
    for(var idx in obj) {
      console.log(idx, obj[idx]);
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It has parsed the JSON correctly and returned an array of objects. You could do the following to access the first item containing `{ data1: "A" }`:

`console.log(tessst[0])`